# electron.js ipcMain and ipcRenderer don't work

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

I try to send a data from `main.html` to `main.js` usin ipc but when I try the method in a yt tutorial `ipcMain.on` don't work here my codes:

```js
const electron = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, ipcMain } = electron;
let mainWindow;
app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow =  new BrowserWindow({});
    mainWindow.loadURL(
        url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, "main.html"),
            protocol: "file:",
            slashes: true
        })
    );
    const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);
    ipcMain.on("key", (event, data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
const mainMenuTemplate = [
    {
        label : "Dosya",
        submenu : [
            {
                label : "Yenile",
                role : "reload"
            },
            {
                label : "Çıkış Yap",
                role : "quit"
            },
            {
                label : "Geliştirici Penceresini Aç/Kapa",
                click(item, focusedWindow){
                    focusedWindow.toggleDevTools();
                }
            },
            {
                label : "Bilgi Menüsü"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

```html
<h1>Deneme Sayfası</h1>
<button onclick="clicked()">Deneme</button>
<script>
    const electron = require('electron');
    const { ipcRenderer } = electron;

    function clicked(){
        ipcRenderer.send("key", "Veri Deneme");
    }
</script>
```

(Some parts are not english jus ignore them)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
mainWindow =  new BrowserWindow({ 
webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }});
```

And Move

```
 ipcMain.on("key", (event, data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

before

```
const mainMenuTemplate
```

For html page
You have two options:

1. put initialization at top of the page

```
 <script>
      const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
    </script>
```

2. put initialization locally

```
function clicked() {
  const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
   ipcRenderer.send("key", "Veri Deneme");
}
```

Comment: I try it and console give error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ipcRenderer' before initialization
    at clicked (main.html:8)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (main.html:2)

Comment: I had a similar problem with ipc within "app.on('ready', () => ...". I didn't find the reason why it didn't work, but rather messaged main from the renderer process, to make it send the information I wanted. That worked.